# Overriding symfony2 component

Tags: symfony, overriding

Can anyone of you help me with an example of how to override symfony's component. In my case I need to override Session class from Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session.php

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? This may help you with using custom session handlers http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html

Comment: I need to override "start" method of session class to disallow to start session for frontend only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the `session.class` parameter in `config.yml`:

```
parameters:
    session.class: Foo\Bar\Session
```